# Ошибка запуска laravel octane через sail

Tags: php, laravel, docker

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всем привет, я новичок в докере и в laravel, хотел протестировать laravel octane, через sail,

у самого window использовал wsl2 ubuntu, создал проект установил sail, запустил докер контейнеры, позже установил laravel octane, но при запуске сервера каждый раз пишет "Server is already running" - при том что сам не запускал, переход на 127.0.0.0:8000 не даёт результатов, можете подсказать в чем дело?

пробывал и перезапускать docker, и пересоздавать проект, и ставить по многу раз octane